# EF Core set Original Values in Disconnected Scenario

Tags: ef-core-2.2

I am using `DBContext.Update(ParentEntity)` to update an entity. Then I loop through each of the Entities `property.CurrentValue` and `property.OriginalValue`. 
The problem I am facing is that **CurrentValues** and **OriginalValues** are the same even though one Property has been changed and is different from the DB. I was expecting to get **OriginalValues** from the Database. 
Heres the loop that happens before saving changes.

```
foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (entry.Entity is Audit || entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged ||entry.Entity is ChangelogUser)
                continue;

            var auditEntry = new AuditEntry(entry) {TableName = entry.Metadata.Relational().TableName};
            auditEntries.Add(auditEntry);

            foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
            {
                if (property.IsTemporary)
                {
                    // value will be generated by the database, get the value after saving
                    auditEntry.TemporaryProperties.Add(property);
                    continue;
                }

                string propertyName = property.Metadata.Name;
                if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                {
                    auditEntry.KeyValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                    continue;
                }

                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        if (property.CurrentValue != null)
                        {
                            if (property.OriginalValue != null && property.CurrentValue != null)
                            {
                                if (property.IsModified && !property.CurrentValue.Equals(property.OriginalValue))
                                {
                                    auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                                    auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }
```

From this code I AWLAYS get the same Original and Current values. Is there some way to get the Original Values from the DB and set them on the Entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is suuuper difficult to get an answer for EFCore Questions here´s the solution I came up with.

Check out the **State.Modified** section. I Iterate through each entity and then iterate through each property. In this case, I am using the current and original values to compare them and only add them to my audit table when something has changed.

At the **end** of the method I remove the Entities that have not changed from my audit table. Simple mimple.

You could use this the `var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();` To for your custom disconnected scenario needs.

```
var auditEntries = new List<AuditEntry>();
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {

            if (entry.Entity is Audit || entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
                continue;

            var auditEntry = new AuditEntry(entry) {TableName = entry.Metadata.Relational().TableName};
            auditEntries.Add(auditEntry);

            var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

            foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
            {
                if (property.IsTemporary)
                {
                    // value will be generated by the database, get the value after saving
                    auditEntry.TemporaryProperties.Add(property);
                    continue;
                }

                string propertyName = property.Metadata.Name;
                if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                {
                    auditEntry.KeyValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                    continue;
                }

                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        if (property.CurrentValue != null)
                        {
                            if (databaseValues[propertyName] != null && property.CurrentValue != null)
                            {
                                if (property.IsModified && !property.CurrentValue.Equals(databaseValues[propertyName]))
                                {
                                    auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = databaseValues[propertyName];
                                    auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }

            if (auditEntry.NewValues.Equals(auditEntry.OldValues) || auditEntry.NewValues.Count == 0 && auditEntry.OldValues.Count == 0)
            {
                auditEntries.Remove(auditEntry);
            }
```